# Firebase search implementation using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am a very new to the idea of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and hence have a very basic question  to ask. I am using this code to make an app where users can enter their profession/service. Then I want their profiles to be displayed when they search using their profession names. This is the code I am using:

```
private TextInputLayout searchServicees;
private Button searchBtn;
private RecyclerView serviceesList;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    searchServicees=findViewById(R.id.searchServicees);
    searchBtn=findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
    serviceesList=findViewById(R.id.serviceesList);
    serviceesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    serviceesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String searchTxt=searchServicees.getEditText().getText().toString();
            firebaseSearch(searchTxt);
        }
    });
}

private void firebaseSearch(String search)
{
    Query firebaseQuery=databaseReference.orderByChild("service_Offered").startAt(search).endAt(search+"\uf8ff");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserSearch,UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserSearch, UsersViewHolder>(
            UserSearch.class,R.layout.list_layout,UsersViewHolder.class,firebaseQuery)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserSearch model) {
            holder.setDetails(model.getCost_inDollars(),model.getDescription_Of_Service(),model.getName(),model.getService_Offered());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout,viewGroup,false);
            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    serviceesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;
    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
    }
    public void setDetails(String userCost,String userDes,String userName,String userService)
    {
        TextView name=mView.findViewById(R.id.searchName);
        TextView service=mView.findViewById(R.id.searchService);
        TextView des=mView.findViewById(R.id.searchDes);
        TextView cost=mView.findViewById(R.id.searchCost);

        name.setText(userName);
        service.setText(userService);
        des.setText(userDes);
        cost.setText(userCost);
    }
}
```

Now in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(
            UserSearch.class,R.layout.list_layout,UsersViewHolder.class,firebaseQuery)
part it shows the error of:

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter() in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to:

Expected Parameters: options:
com...com.example.servicees.UserSearch>

Actual Arguments:

com...com.example.servicees.UserSearch>
UserSearch.class  (java...com.example.servicees.UserSearch>)

R.layout.list_layout  (int)

UsersViewHolder.class  (java...SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder>)

firebaseQuery  (com.google.firebase.database.Query)

Could anyone please tell me where am I doing wrong?